# Codeception Tests take 'default' datasource instead of 'test' in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp-3.0, codeception

I'm able to run UnitTests via Codeception, but when it comes to database and fixtures its confusing...

My codeception.dist.yml

```
namespace: App\TestSuite\Codeception
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tmp/tests
    data: tests/Fixture
    support: src/TestSuite/Codeception
    envs: tests/Envs
settings:
    bootstrap: bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=%DB_HOST_TEST%;dbname=%DB_NAME_TEST%'
            user: '%DB_USER_TEST%'
            password: '%DB_PASSWORD_TEST%'
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
            cleanup: true # reload dump between tests
            populate: true # load dump before all tests
            reconnect: true
    enabled:
        - Db
params:
    - env
```

The dump.sql is imported into the test database on running my tests. Fixtures are not inserted...

Then in my Test I do something like this (shortened):

```
<?php
namespace App\Test\Unit\Model\Behavior;

use App\Model\Behavior\HashableBehavior;
use App\Model\Entity\User;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;

/**
 * App\Model\Behavior\HashableBehavior Test Case
 */
class HashableBehaviorTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
/**
 * Test subject
 *
 * @var \App\Model\Behavior\HashableBehavior
 */
public $Hashable;

public $fixtures = [
    'app.Users',
    'app.mandators'
];

/**
 * Test subject
 *
 * @var \App\Model\Table\UsersTable
 */
public $UsersTable;

/**
 * setUp method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $config = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->exists('Users') ? [] : ['className' => UsersTable::class];
    $this->UsersTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users', $config);

    $this->Hashable = new HashableBehavior($this->UsersTable);
}

/**
 * tearDown method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function tearDown()
{
    unset($this->Hashable);

    parent::tearDown();
}

/**
 * Test beforeSave method
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function testBeforeSave()
{
    $user = $this->UsersTable->get(1);
    ...

}
```

This gives me the first record from my default database and not from the test database. I have no Idea what is missing here... Glad for any help!

Comment: Sounds like CakePHPs fixture manager isn't running (that's where the default connection is exchanged for the test connection). Are you using **https://github.com/cakephp/codeception**? If not, you might want to give it a try, as CakePHP doesn't integrate with Codeception on its own.

Comment: Yes I use github.com/cakephp/codeception - main problem is the week documentation...

Comment: What does your `tests/Unit.suite.yml` file look like? Specifically, does it enable the `\Cake\Codeception\Framework` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking all the code again I found in tests/bootstrap.php this lines:

```
if (getenv('db_dsn')) {
    putenv('DATABASE_URL=' . getenv('db_dsn'));
    putenv('DATABASE_TEST_URL=' . getenv('db_dsn'));
}
```

Even I could not find the place where the variable DATABASE_TEST_URL is used, adding this to my .env file solved it:

```
export db_dsn="mysql://db_usr:db_password@db_host/db_name?encoding=utf8&timezone=UTC&cacheMetadata=true&quoteIdentifiers=false&persistent=false"
```

Variable DATABASE_TEST_URL is in .env but has no effect on this... I think its that cakePHP and Codeception doesn't magically integrate too well.

Still my fixtures are not loaded in UnitTests (class MyTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit) - in but the question is solved.

[UPDATE] Fixture loading fixed. I have to manually inject the FixtureManager and load my fxtures in setUp function.